# Use elapsed days in german ms project

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

As I've found out recently, there is a way to use elapsed days (instead of working days in MS Project). But I use german MS project and there you can't use the english words. You have to stick with german wording. But the german equivalent doesn't work out well. I've tried so far:

- ed
- edays
- Vergangene Tage
- Verstrichene Tage
- ver t
- etage

If you know a office.com reference for all english time shortcuts (including elapsed days), it might also help, because they translate most office.com websites in other languages. But so far the only reference I've found is https://support.office.com/de-de/article/Create-and-link-tasks-with-Project-2007-368ab1ee-d6de-4511-9948-888680b35d3d which is not available in german (-_-)

Regards

Comment: The German shortcut is "fTage" (fortlaufende). The Leveling Delay field was giving me the hint.

Answer (score 4):

Insert the task Leveling Delay field into a table and read the unit abbreviation from there.  Leveling Delay is always in elapsed days.

This will give you the answer in any language.  German for elapsed days is fTage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was giving me the hint to the corresponding german unit abbreviation. You might add it to your answer, so I can accept it as the answer. "fTage" (fortlaufende)